# List Adapter Only Adding 1 Item to List View

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am creating a comments section for an application, and every time I click the "comment" button, I want to add the comment to my ListView.

Unfortunately, my code is only allowing me to add 1 comment to my ListView. Every time I type and click the add comment button, the ListView remains static at 1 item.

I believe I have to modify the getCount() method in my Customer Adapter, but I wanted to seek assistance

Below is my code:

```
public class Discussion_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mUserComment;
private String mUserID;
private ImageView mUserAvatar;
private ListView mPollComments;
private ArrayAdapter<Comments> mCommentAdapter;
private Firebase mBaseRef;
private int mCommentCounter;

private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://fan-polls.firebaseio.com/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_discussion);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mBaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    mUserComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_comment);
    mUserAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image_avatar);
    mPollComments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poll_comments_list);
    final ArrayList<Comments> pollComments = new ArrayList<Comments>();
    mCommentAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.individual_comment, pollComments);
    mPollComments.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);
    mCommentCounter = 0;
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_comment_button);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pollComments.add(mCommentCounter, new Comments(mUserAvatar, mBaseRef.getAuth().getUid(), mUserComment.getText().toString() ));
            mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mCommentCounter++;
            hideKeyboard(view);
            mUserComment.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comments> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Comments> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCommentCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.individual_comment, null);
        }

        Comments p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView userID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
            TextView userComment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_comment);

            if (userID != null) {
                userID.setText(p.getUserID());
            }

            if (userComment != null) {
                userComment.setText(p.getUserComment());
            }
        }


        return v;
    }

  }

}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poll_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".475"
        android:background="@drawable/heyward"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textlines">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image_avatar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/empty_avatar_256x256"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/user_comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
                android:hint="Enter a comment....."
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_comment_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:clickable="true" />


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/poll_comments_list"
            android:divider="@drawable/list_divide"
            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </ListView>


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are adding items directly into `ListView`. You should manage a global list of `Comments` and share it with your `ListAdapter`.

Please notice that in this way you don't need `mCommentCounter` variable at all.

Then, add new comments to this list and notify your adapter. Below I provided you updated code. Let me know if it works for you.

```
public class Discussion_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mUserComment;
    private String mUserID;
    private ImageView mUserAvatar;
    private ListView mPollComments;
    private List<Comments> mComments;
    private ArrayAdapter<Comments> mCommentAdapter;
    private Firebase mBaseRef;

    private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://fan-polls.firebaseio.com/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_discussion);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        private List<Comments> mComments = new ArrayList<Comments>;
        mBaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

        mUserComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_comment);
        mUserAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image_avatar);
        mPollComments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poll_comments_list);
        mCommentAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.individual_comment, mComments);
        mPollComments.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);
        mCommentCounter = 0;
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_comment_button);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mComments.add(new Comments(mUserAvatar, mBaseRef.getAuth().getUid(), mUserComment.getText().toString()));
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideKeyboard(view);
                mUserComment.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comments> {

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Comments> items) {
            super(context, resource, items);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mComments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.individual_comment, null);
            }

            Comments p = getItem(position);

            if (p != null) {
                TextView userID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
                TextView userComment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_comment);

                if (userID != null) {
                    userID.setText(p.getUserID());
                }

                if (userComment != null) {
                    userComment.setText(p.getUserComment());
                }
            }

            return v;
        }

    }

}
```

I noticed now comment about `ScrollView` / `ListView`. This is also a problem. You can keep `ListView` only.

Comment: Is it always conventional to have a customer adapter class within the main class? I was originally going to create a separate class in a model folder but realized I may need some of the variables, thus finding it appropriate to combine the classes

Comment: @tccpg288 You can use a separated class too. Using a separated class is useful in particular if you need to share the same adapter among different layouts (e.g. displaying comments in an activity as well as in a dialog). What is important is that your Activity and Adapter keep reference to the same list of items, so that in case you modify it in Activity you will have changes applied also in adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the timely, helpful response. I am not sure I will be sharing the adapter, but now I understand the purpose of encapsulating the adapter for future use.

Comment: @tccpg288 glad I could help you in understanding something more :)

Answer (score 4):

You call `notifyDataSetChanged()` before increasing the count. Increase the counter before `notifyDataSetChanged()` and it should take the effect

```
mCommentCounter++;
mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can also use the adapter `add` method, thus you don't need to override getCount and have a counter, and also no need to add with index. Adapter add method already adds the item and invokes notifyDataSetChanged

```
adapter.add(new Comments(....));
```

And also scrollview/listview issue as mentioned below answer

Comment: Actually, I think the answer is a combination of this and the answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practise to add one scrollable element to another. You can't make it works without dirty hacks.

So delete yours `ScrollView` and yours `ListView` will work as expected

Comment: This works, but now my new items in the adapter are overlapping the other views on my screen

Comment: @tccpg288, just set other views as HEADER of yours ListView. So yours Layout must contain only ListView with header.